# OOP login page error

Tags: php

using OOP concept I created a login page. I get this error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in C:\xampp\htdocs\oops\Register-form\functions.php on line 12**.

**Code**

```
<?php
include("config.php");
class User
{
  //Db Connect
  public function __construct()
  {
    $db=new db_class();
  }
}
  // Registration Process
  public function register_user($name,$username,$password,$email)
  {
     $password=md5($password);
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from login where username='$username' or emailid='$email'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0)
     {
        $result=mysql_query("insert into login(username,password,name,emailid) values('$username','$password','$name','$email')");
        return result;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: In general, SO is not a debug tool. You have closed class scope before declaring your method. Move your method definition into a class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: did you try anything? like looking at the line 12 at least .. ?

Comment: loll, its not Oops :) its OOP. Oooooops;) will mean something else

Comment: I got this general advice for you: Sticking to a proper code style does avoid 90% of those syntax errors. Take a look at the Zend guide, which is the best imo: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Comment: Last `Wonder` in `OOP`. `Public` function outside the class ...

Comment: Another thing to suggest is, use DI pattern.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code.

Comment: Don't create new objects in your constructor. Pass them into the constructor via Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because function is outside the class. Should be

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    class User
    {
      //Db Connect
      public function __construct()
      {
        $db=new db_class();
      }
      // Registration Process
      public function register_user($name,$username,$password,$email)
      {
         $password=md5($password);
         $sql=mysql_query("select * from login where username='$username' or emailid='$email'");
         if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0)
         {
            $result=mysql_query("insert into login(username,password,name,emailid) values('$username','$password','$name','$email')");
            return result;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you must have some friends around here.. to be the last one to answer such an obvious thing and to be the only one to get a vote up seconds after the answer was posted.. that's strange..

Answer (score 2):

You have closed your class and declared function after the closing of class.So reove that closing before the function declaration and try this

```
class User
{
  //Db Connect
  public function __construct()
  {
    $db=new db_class();
  }//End of constructor

  //Here you have closed the class.so i removed the closing and placed it in the end of class.

  // Registration Process
  public function register_user($name,$username,$password,$email)
  {
     $password=md5($password);
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from login where username='$username' or emailid='$email'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0)
     {
        $result=mysql_query("insert into login(username,password,name,emailid) values('$username','$password','$name','$email')");
        return result;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }//End of function register_user
}//End of class
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
        <?php
    include("config.php");
    class User
    {
      //Db Connect
      public function __construct()
      {
        $db=new db_class();
      }

      // Registration Process
      public function register_user($name,$username,$password,$email)
      {
         $password=md5($password);
         $sql=mysql_query("select * from login where username='$username' or emailid='$email'");
         if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0)
         {
            $result=mysql_query("insert into login(username,password,name,emailid) values('$username','$password','$name','$email')");
            return result;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
}
```

you have closed braces after constructor. So please close on end.

Answer (score -1):

All the class function should be inside the class definition. Then you can call `I am doing OOP` not `I end up with OOOOPS`

```
Class  
{
   public function() 
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: the question has already been answered 3 times

Comment: Yes it is answered. So any rules that I can not put my way of answering to it ?

Comment: Don't stick with your Ideas.. Everybody trying to correct the code. But a proper teacher should show him the basic ...